# Event not fired .NET / XAML

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, events

I have a button and when it is clicked, an event should be raised. I declare the event in one class, but I invoke it in another.
Here is my code:
XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="btnAddUsers"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,15,60" Padding="5,0,5,0"  Click="ImportButton_Click" Content="Add"></Button>
```

Event declaration and the Click method:

```
Public Event GettingADUsers()
Private Sub ImportButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnADAddUsers.Click
        RaiseEvent GettingADUsers()
End Sub
```

In another class I invoke the event (I invoke it in the constructor):

```
AddHandler StaffSettings.GettingADUsers, AddressOf ctlStaff_GettingAllUsers
```

And the method:

```
Private Sub ctlStaff_GettingAllUsers()
    adUsers.Load()
End Sub
```

Do I miss something?